# NVM command works in terminal but not in screen

Tags: node.js, gnu-screen, nvm

I am trying to have multiple connections to my dev server by ssh-ing once into my server and the using screen to open multiple sessions. My problem is that when I run nvm command in screen, the command can not be found. When I exit screen and run the command in the pure ssh terminal it runs fine. I think this is a PATH problem. I wanted to get an absolute path for nvm to see if I can run that in screen.

I ran the code below to find the path

```
 ~$ nvm
 //SHOWS USAGE INFO

 ~$ whereis nvm
 nvm:

 ~$ screen
 //LOADS INTO SCREEN SESSION

 ~$ nvm
 bash: nvm: command not found
```

What does this mean for the install of nvm. If I change its install directory could I then run it in screen.
If this is the case then why wouldn't screen run nvm in the first place.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try manually activating nvm with:

```
source ~/.nvm/nvm.sh
```

Comment: Still works in 2019 as a fix for `command -v nvm` returning nothing. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
which nvm
```

instead of whereis. This will give you the full path.

Comment: This returns nothing. ~$ which nvm   ~$

Answer (score 0):

On startup of a terminal I need to run .nvm.sh before I can execute nvm. I put .nvm.sh into my .bashrc. Turns out that an ssh connection runs the .bashrc but a screen connection does not. This is why the command was not available in screen. I had to manually run .nvm.sh.